# QTP - QC Test architecture

Tags: qtp, hp-quality-center, hp-uft

I wrote a large Function Library in QTP (now UFT) to test a web site. The various functions are called by an Action script driven by an .xls file. Test data is also included in the .xls file.

I can currently turn on and off functions by editing the .xls file. This works fine for me but I would like to turn it over for testers to run from QC and have it be mostly hands off. What would be the best way to accomplish this? I could create many versions of the action script and keep the monolithic qfl, but that could be a maintenance issue.

Is there a way to configure QC to call the various portions of the test via the lab? Any other options for setting this up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes you can execute all your UFT scripts from HP ALM. Under Test resources you can import every thing. Refer to Test Resource module of HP ALM. Thanks